# How to show all marker title in googlemap in android

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have three marker in my googlemap api v2. I am trying to show all the marker title at a time. But it shows only the last marker (myMarker3) title only. My code is given below.

```
Marker myMarker1 = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(myLoc1)
                    .title("Marker 1")
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));
            myMarker1.showInfoWindow();

Marker myMarker2 = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(myLoc2)
                    .title("Marker 2")
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));
            myMarker2.showInfoWindow();

Marker myMarker3 = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(myLoc3)
                    .title("Marker 3")
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_GREEN)));
            myMarker3.showInfoWindow();
```

Here `myLoc1`, `myLoc2` and `myLoc3` are `LatLng` type variable with specific lat and lon.

Comment: https://github.com/ErNaveen/google_map_sample/blob/master/googlemap_sample/src/com/example/mapdemo/MarkerDemoActivity.java

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only one can be shown at a time, because

- That would break compatibility
- would require many bitmaps to be sent via RPC.

So use custom marker icon and Canvas to draw the marker title which could look like info window. Also you can use the official utils [here](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils).

For more details, please refer to  [here](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5240) and [here](https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=5240).